# Facebook user search with graph api returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting an empty Array on user search if the query is not specific.

Meaning, when I use:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=shlomi.schwartz&type=user&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAE5LVc14njXWThH8LE8kxGlCYAUwShVMmNSFixn85pk1baLMAC8gJaqX5QHVEOpwebUv5ilYiW09yThHCxaMJdQa9QZDZD

I'm getting the result

But if I remove 1 letter from the user name I'm getting an empty array:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=shlomi.schwart&type=user&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAE5LVc14njXWThH8LE8kxGlCYAUwShVMmNSFixn85pk1baLMAC8gJaqX5QHVEOpwebUv5ilYiW09yThHCxaMJdQa9QZDZD

I'm trying to implement an auto-complete input for user search, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend, its reported buggy since a july .
 http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/104388699704651/

Comment: Thanks, so how would one implement an all users auto-complete search?

Comment: You could look into FQL, until they fix it.

Comment: right, that was my direction as well. I'll post my solution once I've done